# Where does the money from speeding tickets go in Massachusetts?

Tags: massachusetts, speeding, fines

I have noticed a significant drop in both local speed traps and predatory cruising by state police in Massachusetts. At a number of well-known speed trap locations I have not seen a car in many years. My suspicion is that somehow the way the money is getting distributed has changed and this has reduced the incentive for setting speed traps. So, my question is two fold: how is the money from speeding tickets get allocated currently, and has that changed in the last 10 years?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is generally a political decision, not a legal one.

Comment: "how is the money from speeding tickets get allocated currently, and has that changed in the last 10 years?" seems of a legal nature to me.

Comment: This is  a question about what the law currently provides as to the disposition of money from fines, and what changes there have been in such law. **Why** the law is what it is, or what it should be, are political questions, but the OP did not ask those.

Comment: There could be both legal and political aspects of this.  For instance, it could be that by law, all fines simply go into the state general fund, but maybe the legislature is likely (as a political decision) to increase the budget of departments that bring in revenue.